# Divide by zero error using Sigma notation

Tags: mathcad

I am trying to do a a sigma operation on this but MathCad gives this strange error. How can I go past this or replace the position by 0? Thanks
[image: DivideByZero Erro]

I have tried a for loop but does not work.

Comment: Can you please write down these 10 numbers for us?

Comment: The error pops up at n =5 i.e. 1 / (5-5). Should I write all out in decimals  or fraction?

Comment: Ah ok. It seams that 1/(5-5) cannot be calculated. What do you want as result for 1/(5-5)?

Comment: I want 0 at that spot. Thanks in advance

Comment: But then you cannot use that formula. You must write sum(1..4)(1/n-5) + sum(6..10)(1/n-5) instead. Or you define a simple helper function, that returns 0 if n=5 and 1/(n-5) otherwise.

Comment: I am not sure how to do an if statement on mathcad with a for loop. I want a more generic code that can be easily extended to fit more complex form. Writing out all expressions for n = 1....100 is impractical. Thanks again